# C# returning different types from function

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have written a following code which basically performs a JSON request towards my server:

```
   var client = new RestClient("mysite.com");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", /*params here...*/ ,ParameterType.RequestBody);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCustomType>(client.Execute(request).Content);
```

Please note the last line of code:

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCustomType>(client.Execute(request).Content);
```

Where i de-serialize the returned JSON from server to a previously class structures in my application.

Now the problem is that server can either return error response or success response, and for each of those cases i need a different class structure so that  I can map them to C# class objects...

So I thought something like this would do:

```
public object PerformMyAwesomeRequest(string myToken) 
{
 var response =client.Execute(request).Content;
 var statusCode = FetchStatusCode(response);
if(statusCode == 0)//signaling the response returned error
{
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorMessageCustomType>(response);
}
else{
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCustomType>(response);
}
}
```

So this way it doesn't gives me any errors... But the problem here is that these objects now only exist in runtime, and I cannot determine which type server returned in my .NET MVC Action which looks like this:

```
public ActionResult SomeActon(){
var response = PerformMyAwesomeRequest("mytokenhere...");
//response object is assigned a corresponding type only at runtime...
}
```

So my question here is:

- What type can I return from my function that performs the http request towards the server so that I can know which type was returned from the function directly at code and not only in runtime ?

Comment: How about HttpResponseMessage ?

Comment: @kaarthickraman can u elaborate a little bit more , I'm not sure ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way for a method to return objects of different types is to return their common base type. However, you already discovered that the common superclass of `object` is of no help to you, so let's consider alternatives to returning an object in the first place:

- **Return on success and throw on error** - this approach lets you return `MyCustomType`, and throw some exception wrapping `ErrorMessageCustomType`. Since one object is returned, and the other is thrown, there is no requirement for the types to be related.
- **Return a combined object** - make class with members for each type you plan to return, and set only one of them in the `PerformMyAwesomeRequest` method. This is not as good, because it requires a chain of `if`-`else`s in the caller.
- **Accept an `out` parameter for the error** - if the request is unsuccessful, return `null`, and set the `out` parameter to `ErrorMessageCustomType`.
- **Accept callback delegates** - rather than returning a value, accept two delegates, one for success, and one for the failure scenario, i.e. `void PerformMyAwesomeRequest(string tok, Action<MyCustomType> onSuccess, Action<ErrorMessageCustomType> onError)`.

The last approach can be used like this:

```
PerformMyAwesomeRequest(
    myToken
,   data => {
        Console.WriteLine("Received data: {0}", data);
    }
,   error => {
        Console.WriteLine("Received error: {0}", error);
    }
);
```

The method can be implemented like this:

```
public void PerformMyAwesomeRequest(string myToken, Action<MyCustomType> onSuccess, Action<ErrorMessageCustomType> onError) {
    var response = client.Execute(request).Content;
    var statusCode = FetchStatusCode(response);
    if (statusCode != 0) {
        onSuccess(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCustomType>(response));
    } else {
        onError(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorMessageCustomType>(response));
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the last scenario with callback delegates. Could you just show me an example of usage with this last scenario in my case? =)

Comment: And how do I signal in function whether it is success or error since function is void ?

Comment: @User987 You don't need this signaling, since the result is delivered out-of-bound. In other words, only one of the two callbacks will be activated as the result of the call, not two, so if your code finds itself in the `data` callback, it can assume there was no error, and vice versa.

Comment: so as the last line I do only this: client.Execute(request).Content and it's all good ? o.o

Comment: @User987 Your code looks at the content, and decides which callback to call. I edited to explain what happens in the implementation.

Comment: ah ty so mcuh, I understand now !!=)